# How to deploy Excel 2010 add-in for Office 2007 .NET 3.5 target environment?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, deployment, vsto, windows-installer

Installing Excel 2010 add-in on the target machine with Office 2010 + .Net framework 4.0 is absolutely fine. However, I am not sure whether or not Excel 2010 add-in is compatible with Excel 2007 and .Net 3.5.

Would someone give me some basic ideas about deploying Excel 2010 add-in for that target environment?

Also, in the Prerequisites of setup project, I have currently got `.NET 4 client profile` , `VS2010 tools for office runtime`, `Windows Installer 3.1` checked. Do I need to check any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the primary interop assemblies for Excel 2007 installed?

See this for [detailed documentation on how to deploy VSTO 2010 add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx).

Comment: Hmm. so you are saying I should check Office 2007 PIA option in prerequisites section?

Comment: Also thanks for the link, I am having a look at that right now.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

Managed to install Excel 2010 Add-in onto target machine that runs Office 2007. Mostly the steps have been covered by [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx) but there are a few tricks that we need to be aware of.

Main project

- Be sure to check the target framework of your application in your main project

Setup project

- In registry editor, create following new keys in additional to those suggested in the above tutorial, if you are deploying automation add-in (e.g. **HKCR \ CLSID \ {your custom class id} \ Programmable**)
- Set **Programmable** key to `AlwaysCreate = True`  ( The UDF will not appear in the automation server list if you don't create this Key and set it properly )
- In launch conditions editor, Add `Windows Installer Search`, and rename it `Search for Office 2007 Shared PIA`
- Set **ComponentId** to `{1ABEAF09-435F-47D6-9FEB-0AD05D4EF3EA}` ( This is Excel 2007 Component ID )
- (For Excel 2010, use `{EA7564AC-C67D-4868-BE5C-26E4FC2223FF}`)